# Can I factory reset my jailbroken device without upgrading the iOS version?

Tags: ios, ipad, upgrade, jailbreak

As the title says - I need to do a factory reset on my iPad Mini, but I don't want to upgrade the iOS version while doing it. Is this possible at all or will I have to make do and upgrade iOS as I am factory resetting the device?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [Cydia Impactor](http://www.cydiaimpactor.com/). It is available in the Telesphoreo repository (of Cydia), in the Utilities category.

Comment: Can I restore a backup of my device(through iTunes) after using this?

Comment: Also, this seems to require me to have iOS >=8.1. Is there something for iOS 6.1?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I believe you can restore a backup of your device when it was jail broken (you won't have any of your jailbreak tweaks of course). If you are asking if you can restore backups at all on a device Cydia Impactor has been ran on, then yes.

Comment: I do not know of anything for iOS 6.1, but you could modify the source of Cydia Impactor to get it to run on 6.1 or ask the developer of Cydia and Cydia Impactor: saurik@saurik.com

Answer (score 0):

If you have made a backup before you made the jailbreak you can do it easily with itunes.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Can you be a little more complete in your answer?